# How to check an image is 360 panoramic or not in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-image, panoramas, 360-panorama

I was working on a project where I have to determine an image is 360 panoramic or not. Is there any way to determine that property from an image?

Comment: It is unlikely that these images have some internal differences that would be consistent. It would be much easier to just track height to width ratio and treat images as panoramic or not based on it.

Comment: @vladko312 Is there any specific height to width ratio for determining a panoramic image?

Comment: no, it depends on your tasks. You can consider all images with one side two or three times larger than the other as panoramic, but you can make restrictions much harder if you need.